# Recreate R Plot in Python - change color based on ranges of 3rd value

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

I am trying to recreate the plot below in Python but I cannot figure out how to color the point based on specific ranges from a third value "Density".

This is all I have in Python:

```
plt.plot(df.Date, df.SWE_mm, c='b', marker=',', markersize=10, label='SWE')
```

This is my R code:

```
Plot.df <- ggplot(df, aes(Date, SWE_mm)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut(Density, c(-Inf, 30, 35, 40, Inf))),
             size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Density",
                     values = c("(-Inf,30]" = "grey",
                                "(30,35]" = "yellow",
                                "(35,40]" = "orange",
                                "(40, Inf]" = "red"),
                     labels = c("<= 30]", "(30-35]", "(35-40]" ,"> 40"))+
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Central Sierra Snow Lab", colour = NULL, title = NULL)+
  theme_classic()+
  xlim(c(as.POSIXct('2010-10-01 00:00:00', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),as.POSIXct('2019-09-30 23:00:00', format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,2000))
```

[image: desired plot]

Comment: Could you include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can provide you with help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pandas [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to create the ranges, and seaborn's [`scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dates = pd.date_range('2012-01', '2020-09', freq='W')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates,
                   'SWE (mm)': np.abs(np.random.randn(len(dates)).cumsum()*400 + 1500),
                   'Density': np.random.randn(len(dates)).cumsum() + 35})
df['Density range'] = pd.cut(df['Density'], [-np.inf, 30, 35, 40, np.inf])

sns.scatterplot(x='Date', y='SWE (mm)', hue='Density range', data=df,
                palette=['grey', 'gold', 'orange', 'crimson'])
plt.margins(x=0.02)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: For labels similar to the R example, add them to `pd.cut`:

```py
df['Density range'] = pd.cut(df['Density'], [-np.inf, 30, 35, 40, np.inf],
                             labels=['≤ 30', '(30-35]', '(35-40]', '> 40'])
```